Running Armv8 Assembly Code on an Android Smartphone
I have been recently diving into assembly language programming for the Armv8 architecture and I want to practice my skills in the language. The only problem is, I have an Intel x86-64 machine and I can't directly run my Arm code on there.
However, I do have my android smartphone, Realme x7 pro 5G, which has the Dimensity 1000+ processor. It features an octa-core CPU configuration with four high-performance ARM Cortex-A77 cores and four power-efficient ARM Cortex-A55 cores, all based on ARMv8 architecture. Additionally, it integrates a Mali-G77 GPU for graphics processing and supports various AI (Artificial Intelligence) and multimedia features. Is there any way to run my compiled arm code directly on my phone processor?

run JNI on Android NDK

Yes, if you put your Android phone in Developer Mode, then you can use adb to transfer your executable onto the phone (eg at /data/local/tmp), and run it there. You will want to target Android when you compile.
Latest Android Studio offers a more graphics based UI to get you results on and off, as well as an editing suite should you want to wrap your code in an Android app for ease of use.
Profiling can be done through Streamline and the Arm Performance Studio set of tools to be able to see how well your assembly code is doing.
Buying a Raspberry Pi is another cheap & easy way of getting Arm code running/tested.

Thank you for your answer! I'll definitely try buying a raspberry buy if this doesn't work out.

If you're happy with the answer, do you want to mark it as accepted/upvote it?

i cannot do that since i need to have at least 15 reputation, im terribly sorry
